# The rule of the output columns in pandas.merge()

Tags: pandas, pandas-merge

When I use `pandas.merge`, there's a strange output and I can't understand the real rules of output columns after calling `merge()`.

The source code(pandas is v1.5.2):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series([100, 200, 300], index=[4,5,6], name="A")
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[100,1,1,1],[200,2,2,2],[300,3,3,3]], index=[4,5,6],columns=list("ABCD"))
df3 = pd.merge(
    s1,
    df2,
    suffixes=("_left", "_right"),
    how="left",
    left_index=True,
    right_on="A",
)
print(df3)
```

The output is:

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU0It.png)

```
     A  A_left  A_right   B   C   D
NaN  4     100      NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN  5     200      NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN  6     300      NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

So here is the question, why the second column (labeled with `A`) has the values of the input series' index, and `A` is converted to a column, not index?

Further more, can anyone give a more detailed explanation of the rule of the output columns of the merge API?

I have read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) but it's a little brief.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the name of a `Series`:

```
>>> s1
4    100
5    200
6    300
Name: A, dtype: int64
#     ^--- A is the name of the values not the index

>>> s1.to_frame()
     A  # it becomes the name of the column when your convert it as DataFrame
4  100
5  200
6  300

>>> s1.rename_axis('MyIndex')
MyIndex  # now the index has a name
4    100
5    200
6    300
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

In your code you try to find a relation between the index of `s1` (which has no name) and the 'A' column of `df2`. So you try to match [4, 5, 6] with [100, 200, 300] which doesn't make sense.

However, what you should do is:

```
>>> pd.merge(s1, df2, on='A', how='left', suffixes=("_left", "_right"))
     A  B  C  D
0  100  1  1  1
1  200  2  2  2
2  300  3  3  3
```

If you want to join by index, you have to use:

```
>>> pd.merge(s1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=("_left", "_right"))
   A_left  A_right  B  C  D
4     100      100  1  1  1
5     200      200  2  2  2
6     300      300  3  3  3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my point is that why `[4,5,6]` is in the column `A` of the output, not the index? `[4,5,6]` is defined as the index in both `s1` and df2. And this is a `left` merge. The data of `s1` should be output correctly no matter how many rows are matched.

Comment: Anyway, the join between some indexes in the left and some columns in the right should be allowed.